# Не запускается проект PHP в NetBeanse

Tags: php, netbeans

Доброе время суток. Установил  NetBeanse, создал простой проект на PHP. Запускаю, а сервер просто не работает:"Не удается получить доступ к сайту.Сайт nnnn не позволяет установить соединение".
В чем проблема? Возможно что-то нужно настроить? Погуглил, и ничего не нашел. Может у кого-то была ситуация подобная. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, чтобы проекты NetBeans, находились в каталоге, в котором находятся Ваши веб-приложения. По умолчанию NetBeans создает проекты на диске C в моих документах.